# Firefox in a docker container accessible from selenium in another

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, docker

I have a docker container running a rails app (let's call it container A) that needs to do some scraping with watir webdriver using firefox as backend.

I have firefox installed in another container (container B) and I want to be able to pass in container A something like:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path= $DOCKER_RUN_CONTAINER_A
```

So, each time watir launches firefox a new instance of CONTAINER_A launches a new firefox.

I know it's easy to make containers communicate using ports, but how about executables?
And, by the way, does it look like a good design idea isolating firefox in a separate container?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Sad there are no answers. Did you ever get to a point where you could answer it yourself?

Comment: @AbeHeward, I managed to workaround the issue using the elgalu/docker-selenium image and link the image using fig (now called docker-compose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do.  Just run an instance of Selenium Grid (which is a grid-node hybrid combo by default) , in the foreground on the docker server (on port 5555 or whatever).  Then you can use Ruby with Selenium bindings (not WatiR)  to drive the firefox browser on the remote box.